# inappupdate not available after skipping installation

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core

When Users downloads the app via Flexible app update

```
appUpdateManager?.startUpdateFlowForResult(it, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, activity, REQUEST_CODE_FLEXI_UPDATE)
```

but forgets or accidentally skips to click the restart app button which does following:

```
            appUpdateManager?.completeUpdate()
```

Then app update is not available. Even I tried with clear app data, it doesn't work. Looks like once app is downloaded via inappupdate and skips installation, you're stuck, it doesn't ask again.

```
appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo?.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                updateAvailable.value = true
            }
        }
```

Is there a solution to this? Other things are working and it's live on playstore just looking for solution of such use-case.

Also how to get **progress** value of app being downloaded, couldn't find it in documentation. In my case, `onActivityResult` keeps calling but which key gives progress value?

Also facing another issue with different use case: [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while inappupdate android if retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290049/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-while-inappupdate-android-if-retries)

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED` on app restart and call `completeUpdate()` at some point as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#install_flexible).