# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while inappupdate android if retries

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-update, google-play-core

Steps to reproduce this error:

1. Click update button & it opens update app dialog since it's `AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE`.
2. Click `No, thanks`
3. Try update again. App crashes with following error:

I'm getting this exception while updating the app via inappupdate on following line.

```
appUpdateManager?.startUpdateFlowForResult(it, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, activity, REQUEST_CODE_FLEXI_UPDATE) //it == AppUpdateInfo object
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:451)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
Caused by: android.content.IntentSender$SendIntentException
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResultInner(Activity.java:4878)
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:4847)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(FragmentActivity.java:796)
        at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:4814)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(FragmentActivity.java:781)
        at com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.b.startUpdateFlowForResult(Unknown Source:22)
        at newProfile.NewProfileFragment.startForInAppUpdate(NewProfileFragment.kt:752)
        at newProfile.NewProfileFragment.access$startForInAppUpdate(NewProfileFragment.kt:60)
        at newProfile.NewProfileFragment$setupAppUpdate$3.onClick(NewProfileFragment.kt:682)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12752)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26214)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

Details:

Android version: 8.0
Phone: Samsung J7

**Update**

> As per documentation, `startUpdateFlowForResult` should only called for once `AppUpdateInfo` instance. For calling again, you must create `AppUpdateInfo` instance.

but since its instance depends on below condition, how to make sure its instance newly gets created before calling `startUpdateFlowForResult`

```
 appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo?.addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE &&
                    it.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                appUpdateInfo = it
                updateAvailable.value = true
            } else {
                updateAvailable.value = false
            }
        }
```

Also how to get **progress** value of app being downloaded, couldn't find it in documentation. In my case, onActivityResult keeps calling but which key gives progress value?

Also facing another issue with different use case: [inappupdate not available after skipping installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285370/android-inappupdate-not-available-after-skipping-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The documentation of [`IntentSender.SendIntentException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.SendIntentException) says: "_Exception thrown when trying to send through a PendingIntent that has been canceled or is otherwise no longer able to execute the request_". I'm not familiar enough with Android to be of much help, but maybe that documentation can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah but its internal exception of Activity class which even can't be handled due to which app crashes. It shouldn't have appeared in first place.

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#start_update), you can only use an instance of `AppUpdateInfo` one time. Try using a new instance for the retry (if you aren't already).

Comment: @Slaw@Slaw AppUpdateInfo gets initialized if following case:  appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo?.addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE &&
                    it.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                appUpdateInfo = it
                updateAvailable.value = true
            } else {
                updateAvailable.value = false
            }
        }

Comment: I have updated the question.. please check..

Comment: @AskQ, Did you find out solution to re-create AppUpdateInfo

Comment: call this line.. it will newly initiate appUpdateInfo again.. appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo?.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to trigger `startUpdateFlowForResult` with the same `AppUpdateInfo` twice.

As @Slaw suggested, after a failed or canceled update you need to do `appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener` again in order to have another instance of `AppUpdateInfo` to make second call to `startUpdateFlowForResult`

Comment: @Slaw Can you share some code snippet so that it becomes more clear?

Comment: Hi, Gettigi the same crash logs in FIrease. Can you share code to handle this.

Comment: can you share more detail or any eg plz?