# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while doing in app update

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-core

I have integrated the in-app updates feature by Google Play Core library using [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) link.

I am using immediate update option because we make various critical bug fixes regularly which are important to update.

Here are the cases when app doesn't crash and updates app successfully and when it crashes.

1. Click 'Update' button when app update is available and let the update to finish properly without interrupting it in between - App Updated successfully.
2. Click 'Update' button, update starts to download, but user cancels update in middle by pressing 'x' button present after 'Update Download progress bar' - App Update canceled.
3. Try opening app again, it crashes with following error.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:586)
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:942)
>       Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:942)
>       Caused by android.content.IntentSender$SendIntentException
>       android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResultInner (Activity.java:5019)
>       com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.b.startUpdateFlowForResult (Unknown Source:5)
>       co.behtarinternal.app.menu.MenuActivity$checkForAppUpdate$1.onSuccess
>   (MenuActivity.kt:239)
>       co.behtarinternal.app.menu.MenuActivity$checkForAppUpdate$1.onSuccess
>   (MenuActivity.kt:43)
>       com.google.android.play.core.tasks.e.run (Unknown Source:27)
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:942)

I have also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57290049/8345451) question and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58397029/8345451), but cannot understand how this solution can be implemented.

I have searched a lot everywhere, but didn't find any feasible solution related to this problem.

If any of you out there have faced a similar issue, and your solution worked, do help me.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Not till now. Do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Not yet. :-( I saw one crash report with this error recently. Most likely a play core bug. If I find anything, I will let you know here.

Comment: Sure. Do let me know

Comment: I should report this bug to Play Core forum then

Comment: this is a silly question from my side, but do you keep a reference of the `appUpdateManager ` and re-use it, in any way? It seems that the `appUpdateManager ` instance is created from a factory method invocation and it provides a reference to the `appUpdateInfo`. So, if it is re-used, it might be giving you the reference to same old instance of `appUpdateInfo`.

Answer (score 7):

From what I have understand, you are trying to use the same instance of the `AppUpdateInfo` somewhere, where its `Intent` is a rather `PendingIntent` that you are trying to use multiple times. Since a `PendingIntent` can be used only once, it throws the exception. To solve this I am guessing you have an option.

If you are able to reproduce this bug locally, call `startUpdateFlowForResult()` in a try-catch method and try to catch `IntentSender$SendIntentException`, or `InvocationTargetException`. If the exception is catched, that means the `PendingIntent` is used already. Assuming that your `checkUpdates()` method can be used recursively, call `checkUpdates()` again, which should create a new `AppUpdateManager` instance and start the lifecycle again, which will result in a new, fresh `AppUpdateInfo` as a result, hence the new `PendingIntent` that should let you open the app update popup again.

Edit: I'm not sure but what happens when `onResume` code executes again? Like, `checkForUpdates` is called but you are also replacing the `mAppUpdateManager` in `onResume` call, by calling `AppUpdateManager.getInstance(this)`. So, it is a possibility that the `mAppUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo` might not belong to the newly assigned `mAppUpdateManager` in `onResume`, since on application startup both `onCreate` and `onResume` is called. Hence, the object itself may not belong to the `AppUpdateManager` itself.

A solution might be using two different managers, however I think the mechanism itself will return a singleton which makes them both same (maybe?) anyway, you need to check the address endpoints while in debug mode. The debug object should look like `AppUpdateManager@2b62aa`, check if the managers are different or not. If they become different as I predict, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: I will try this method and will tell whether this resolved the bug or not.

Comment: The problem is that, this bug doesn't occur frequently, and not in testing time, it occurs only when I make an update live and users try to download it via in app update. And at that time, this bug occurs for every update which different users do. So it can be viewed only via Crashlytics logs, not locally

Comment: I see. I guess releasing the app with lower percentage and seeing the results remotely is the only option then. Or, you can try beta testing and see if it works.

Comment: Sure, will try that

Comment: Actually, what I am doing right now is that, I am creating a new instance of `AppUpdateManager` everytime the `checkUpdates()` method execution is started, so I guess that will give me a new `AppUpdateInfo` instance everytime `checkUpdates()` method is called right?

Comment: If it is possible can you share the source code of this process? I'm unable to deduce the problem here just by guessing. Maybe if I see the code I can give a better answer.

Comment: Sure, will send you the gist link in a while

Comment: Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/Divya0319/dd5a2a47d92106a6ac1bedd7d7840482

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.

Comment: App update managers are same when checkUpdates is called twice. What to do now?

Comment: Did creating a new app update manager every time solve it for you?